# Why aren't all the records being returned from the data

Tags: excel, vba

Be gentle, this is my first code from scratch and I've just customized stolen code at that. The goal of the code is to retrieve all records in a table that meet three criteria and paste into a specific location. This will be used to make calculations on using my next code foray. I know I need to add messages if there are not any matching records. I want to get this part working first.

```
Sub ListRecords()  

' Declare Variables  
' Clear old results  
' Find records that match criteria  

Dim Part As String  
Dim Hold As String  
Dim Cut As Integer  
Dim LRow As Integer  
Dim i As Integer  

Sheets("Multi Cut Lengths").Range("F21:H71").ClearContents  
Part = Sheets("Multi Cut Lengths").Range("A2").Value  
Hold = Sheets("Multi Cut Lengths").Range("A1000").Value  
Cut = Sheets("Multi Cut Lengths").Range("B3").Value  

Worksheets("FG Inv").Activate  
    LRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  

For i = 2 To LRow  
If Cells(i, 1) = Part And Cells(i, 3) > Cut And Cells(i, 4) = Cut Then  
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy  

    Worksheets("Multi Cut Lengths").Activate  
    Sheets("Multi cut lengths").Range("F35").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats  

    End If  
Next i  
End Sub
```

With the criteria I have defined it should return 20+ records. (confirmed by filtering). I am only seeing the first record.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a loop instead of filtering? That would be the easier way to do this.

Comment: Best practice is to specify which `Worksheet` the `Cells` are on. Since you haven't here, there's an implied `ActiveSheet`. Note that the "Multi Cut Lengths" sheet becomes the active sheet after the first iteration of the loop, so on the second iteration `Cells` does not refer to the cells on the "FG Inv" tab.

Comment: To be honest, I'm using a loop because that seemed easier and cleaner. I should probably try filtering and just copying the first 15 rows.

Comment: Activating the "FG Inv" sheet before going back through the loop worked. Thank you. Now the issue is the last "i" (which doesn't meet the criteria) is pasting over the first "i". I'll try filtering I guess. Do I just do a simple copy and paste of the first 15 after filtering? I only want the first 15 because I'm doing a simplex LP solve on them after which can take some time. Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to grab the cells that are visible after filtering.

Comment: I did try the filtering and got it to work. The code ended up taking several minutes to run versus the original method at less than 30 seconds. I'm not sure why either would be faster than the other but I did revert back to the original. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
 Sheets("Multi cut lengths").Range("F35").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

It essentially 'tells' the macro to go to cell F35 and go all the way up (stops at the first empty cell or the top of Worksheet (row 1).

Perhaps this is the problem? Wrongly specified output range?